# Selecting every X percentile values from a dataset in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a 50k rows dataset and want to select every 10 percentile value in an ordered set.  Ideally it would return 11 values, equally spaced from non-NULL values.

I'm trying to avoid selecting the entire column and doing it in PHP, or doing 10 queries, each selecting a single row based on the total count.

This will be done 7 times per user request for different columns.
(Other query parameters will change, so I can't cache it.)

---

Update: I'm trying to avoid this:

```
$query = "SELECT BLAH BLAH" ;
$result = mysql_query($query);
$num_of_results = mysql_num_rows($result);

//divide count by 10 to get percentile sizes
$number_of_percentiles= 10;
$percentile_size = $num_of_results/ $number_of_percentiles;

//take each of the percentiles of the sample set

for ($a=0; $a<= $number_of_percentiles; $a++){

  $query = "SELECT BLAH BLAH
  LIMIT ". ($a * $percentile_size ).",1";

  $result = mysql_query($query);
  $percentile_array[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
}
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't have the analytic/ranking/windowing functionality you'd typically use for such requirements.

Comment: Do your need WHERE for filtering for your `select blah blah` ?

Comment: Yes, this narrows down the result set to approx 50k rows, even so, the performance is painful.  I tried returning the whole 50k, but it fails due to memory overload

Answer (score 0):

You could:

```
GROUP BY CEIL(`percentage`/10)*10
```

Which would group the rows into 10 percent groups? Need a bit more info or code to help you more.

Comment: interesting!  so if the column consisted of 1,2,3....19,20 it would return 1,3,5...20?  how is `percentage` defined?